# Combine three dictionaries using values Python

Tags: python, dictionary

#### Problem working with dictionaries.

Here is my problem.

I have three tables and need to create a fourth that groups all the information from the previous three.

File 1: contains the keys of interest for table4.

```
file1.txt:
a   namex   23  14
b   nameY   30  18
c   nameZ   10  20
```

File 2: Collect information from [1] and [3] based on the [2].

Generates a dictionary like this:

DICT2 = {'X': ['nameX', 'infoX'] , 'Y': ['nameY', 'infoY'] , 'Z': ['nameZ', 'infoZ']}

```
file2.txt:
[0]     [1]     [2] [3]     [4] [5] 
idX     nameX   X   infoX   ... descriptionX 
idY     nameY   Y   infoY   ... descriptionY
idZ     nameZ   Z   infoZ   ... descriptionZ
```

File 3: the values to 'a' ,'b' and 'c' used to append to the end of DICT1.

```
file3.txt
a   1   0   1   0   0
b   0   3   8   2   0
c   3   5   3   4   1
```

My script:

```
file1 = open('file1.txt', 'r')
file2 = open('file2.txt', 'r')
file3 = open('file3.txt', 'r')

DICT1 = {}
DICT2 = {}
DICT3 = {}

for line in file1:
    row = line.strip().split('\t')
    if row[0] not in DICT1:
        DICT1[row[0]] = row[1:]

for line2 in file2:
    row2 = line2.strip().split('\t')
    if row2[1] not in DICT2:
        DICT2[row2[1]] = row2[2], row2[5]

for line3 in file3:
    row3 = line3.strip().split('\t')
    name = line3[0].strip()
    count = line3[1:]
    if name not in DICT3:
               DICT3[name] = count
               if name in DICT1 and DICT2:

     print(name + '\t' + DICT2[key] + str('\t'.join(count)) + '\t' + 
                                        str('\t'.join(DICT1[name])))
```

When I try to include the values from DICT3  to print occurs that the first key from DICT2 repeats to all (X in the table):

```
a   X   1   0   1   0   0   nameX   23  14
b   X   0   3   8   2   0   nameY   30  18
c   X   3   5   3   4   1   nameZ   10  20
```

The output that I want to obtain is as follows:

```
a   X   1   0   1   0   0   nameX   23  14
b   Y   0   3   8   2   0   nameY   30  18
c   Z   3   5   3   4   1   nameZ   10  20
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What is `orf2` and `DICT2.key[]` and what happened to the indentation at the end?

Comment: I'm having a hard time reproducing your code.  DICT2.key[] shouldn't produce anything, and the 't' preceding it I think should be a '\t'.  Are either of those the issue?

Comment: You probably needed `name = row3[0].strip()` instead of `name = line3[0].strip()`? But I agree with @Ben, I'm unable to understand the objective

Comment: ofr2 = name. Sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's start cleaning up code first, and see if we can get to where you're trying to be

First off, you have text files with delimited data. Anytime you're looking at that, you should lean on the `csv` module to parse it. Don't try and read by-row and split with your delimiter if you have a stdlib module that does it for you. It's too easy to make unexpected implementation errors.

Secondly, open your files using the `with` keyword. This saves you from having to close them later (and possibly forgetting) and is just good practice.

```
import csv

with open("file1.txt") as file1, open("file2.txt") as file2, \
     open("file3.txt") as file3:
    readers = [csv.reader(f, delimiter="\t") for f in [file1, file2, file3]]
    # readers[0] is file1
    # readers[1] is file2
    # readers[2] is file3
```

Now let's look at how you're creating those dictionaries. There's a lot of `if key not in dict: dict[key] = data`. Do you *actually* think you'll have duplicate data and are trying to ignore the rest? If so, good, keep doing it! If not, drop that and do:

```
    # still inside the `with` block from the last snippet

    dicts = []
    dicts.append({k: vs for k, *vs in readers[0]})
    dicts.append({one: (two, five) for _, one, two, _, _, five, *_ in readers[1]}
    dicts.append({k: vs for k, *vs in readers[2]})
    # dicts[0] is DICT1
    # dicts[1] is DICT2
    # dicts[2] is DICT3
```

Now that we have all our data tabulated, we can generate an output:

```
# no longer need to be inside the `with` block

result = [[abbr, dicts[1][name][0], *dicts[2][abbr], name, *vs] for abbr, (name, *vs) in dicts[0].items()]
```

That big old ugly thing should give you the right result, though you'll have to join strings to do it.

```
for row in result:
    print("\t".join(row))
```

### Your code

Your code has a number of errors that makes it tough to break down what, exactly, is going wrong. Things like `DICT2.key[]` in your final print line is probably `DICT2.keys()`, but should be throwing error messages you're not reporting and I hesitate to guess what's gone wrong if the code provided isn't the code written!

Comment: Thank you Adam Smith. I had a problem trying to use your suggestions. The * character at *vs appears as an SyntaxError: invalid syntax.